# Self Join in LINQ is failing when applying to an edmx entity data model

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, edmx

I have below two tables in my EF model. A device may have zero, one or many data calibrations.

**Table 'Equipo'** : This table contains devices. Primary Key is equipoid

```
Id | equipoId  |  Description
1     9474
2     9473
3     9475
```

**Table 'CalibracionVerificacion'** : This table contains calibration data for each device (Device Data Calibration). Primary key is Id.

```
   Id | equipoId | magnitudId | fechaPrevista
     1    9474       0402       2020-05-01 00:00:00.000
     2    9474       0808       2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
     3    9474       0101       2019-12-19 00:00:00.000
     4    9473       2001       2018-02-08 00:00:00.000
     5    9473       1901       2019-05-23 00:00:00.000
     6    9473       1901       2017-08-17 00:00:00.000
     7    9472       0808       2020-11-11 00:00:00.000
     8    9472       0101       2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I need to iterate over each device in table Equipo and perform below steps for each one:

1. In device data calibration,  Group by magnitudId and for each magnitudId obtain the most recent fechaPrevista (Note that magnitudes may be repeated for the same device).
2. Once I have the most recent date and time (fechaPrevista) for each magnitude (magnitudId) I want to obtain the oldest fechaPrevista

So I perform below LINQ expression:

**LINQ Expression**:

```
Dim eq = db.Equipo
For Each equipo As Equipo In eq
   Dim fechaPrevista As DateTime? =
    (From c In equipo.CalibracionVerificacion
     Join c2 In (From c3 In equipo.CalibracionVerificacion
                 Where c3.equipoId = equipo.equipoId AndAlso Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c3.magnitudId))
                 Group c3 By c3.magnitudId Into cgroup = Group
                 Select New With
                 {
                    Key .MagnitudID = magnitudId,
                    Key .MaxDate = cgroup.Max(Function(x) x.fechaPrevista)
                 }
                 ) On New With {.JoinProperty1 = c.magnitudId, .JoinProperty2 = c.fechaPrevista} Equals
                      New With {.JoinProperty1 = c2.MagnitudID, .JoinProperty2 = c2.MaxDate}
                 Where c.equipoId = equipo.equipoId
                 Select c).Min(Function(d) d.fechaPrevista))

    // Do something with fechaPrevista

Next
```

I have checked the same LINQ expression in LINQPad 5 by pointing directly to the database and it is working correctly.

For example, taking into account above tables, for equipoId = 9474 I want to obtain the oldest date and time which is 2019-12-19 00:00:00.000 but I get Nothing as a result of fechaPrevista.

Since I cannot debug the above LINQ expression i have disected the query into parts. I have been debugging the above LINQ expression by separate in two parts: the inner and the outer Linq expression. For the below inner Linq expression : (Suppose that equipo.equipoId = 9474 in this example):

```
Dim c23 = From c3 In equipo.CalibracionVerificacion
          Where c3.equipoId = equipo.equipoId AndAlso Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c3.magnitudId))
          Group c3 By c3.magnitudId Into cgroup = Group
          Select New With
          {
              Key .MagnitudID = magnitudId,
              Key .MaxDate = cgroup.Max(Function(x) x.fechaPrevista)
          }
```

... I get the correct result. It is working and return below results:

[image]

So the inner LINQ expression is working perfectly. The problem is with the outer LINQ expression, the self join is failing and then returns Nothing as result. I do not understand why. Any ideas?

Basically the LINQ expression translated into SQL Server is (for example, to simplify, for one equipoId would be):

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 9474
DECLARE @p1 Int = 9474
-- EndRegion
SELECT MIN([t0].[fechaPrevista]) AS [value]
FROM [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX([t1].[fechaPrevista]) AS [value], [t1].[magnitudId]
    FROM [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[equipoId] = @p0
    GROUP BY [t1].[magnitudId]
    ) AS [t2] ON ([t0].[magnitudId] = [t2].[magnitudId]) AND ([t0].[fechaPrevista] = [t2].[value])
WHERE [t0].[equipoId] = @p1
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ it's helpful to think declaratively (i.e., in terms of the desired result) than imperatively (i.e., control flow). From what I can tell, ultimately you want to iterate over a resultset that has the following properties/fields:

- equipoId
- magnitudId
- first fechaPrevista
- last fechaPrevista

I could be misunderstanding you.  From your description it's not clear whether you want the last fechaPrevista per group vs the last one for all entities/records.  Also, I'm assuming here that you'll want to skip any rows in Equipo that don't have children in CalibracionVerificacion. If my assumptions here are accurate, this should get you what you're after:

```
Dim data = db.CalibracionVerificacion

    Dim qry = (From item in data group by grp = New With {Key item.equipoId, Key item.magnitudId} into finalGrp = Group
        Select New With
            {
                .equipoId = grp.equipoId,
                .magnitudId = grp.magnitudId,
                .firstFechaPrevista = finalGrp.Min(function(g) g.fechaPrevista),
                .lastFechaPrevista = finalGrp.Max(function(g) g.fechaPrevista)
                }).ToList


                For each item in qry
                    'do something               
                next
```

Comment: No,there is no two fechaPrevista(first and last).There is only one fechaPrevista. In CalibracionVerificacion entity, one device (equipoId) may have many magnitudes (magnitudId).In the example,there are not repeated magntiudes for the same device but there could be.For each device,I group by magnitude and get the most recent datetime (fechaPrevista).

Comment: For example, for device 9474 I get the most recent datetime for each magnitude: (0402, 2020-05-01 00:00:00.000), (0808, 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000), (0101,2019-12-19 00:00:00.000) and over this set I get the oldest datetime (fechaPrevista), in this case is '2019-12-19 00:00:00.000'. I do the same for the rest of devices: 9473 and 9472

Comment: As I have observed, the inner linq expression is working but the outer one, the one applying the join is failling. The join fails but I do not know why.

Comment: See the updated post at the end. What I am trying to do in LINQ is the same as translated into SQL Server (to simplify, I have put an example for only one device).